# google ads library issue google.ads.google_ads.client

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

I am working on a project to extract data from Google Ads campaigns using Python. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to use the
'from google.ads.google_ads.client import GoogleAdsClient'

library, and it's giving me the error

> 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.ads.google_ads''.

I have already installed the 'google-ads' library using pip. I'm currently stuck on this problem, and I would appreciate any guidance or solutions from anyone who has experience with this. Your help is highly valued.

Libraries already installed
google                   3.0.0
google-ads               22.1.0
google-api-core          2.14.0
google-auth              2.23.4
google-auth-httplib2     0.1.1
google-auth-oauthlib     1.1.0
googleads                40.0.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.61.0
grpcio                   1.59.3
grpcio-status            1.59.2
proto-plus               1.22.3
protobuf                 3.17.3

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.